# Angular 2: How to use a provider injected while bootstrapping in another service?

Tags: angular

I have problems to understand how to use a provider injected at the root level in other parts of an Angular 2 app.

I have a Factory Provider [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/) that helps with JWT Authentication. I inject it into my `main.ts` where I do the bootstrapping of the app like so:

```
import {provide, enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/platform/common';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {AuthHttp, AuthConfig} from 'angular2-jwt';
import { User } from '../shared/models/user.model';
import {AppComponent} from './app/components/app.component';

if ('<%= ENV %>' === 'prod') { enableProdMode(); }

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(AuthHttp, {
    useFactory: (http: any) => {
      return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        headerPrefix: 'Bearer',
        tokenName: 'auth_token',
        globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type':'application/json'}],
        noJwtError: true,
        noTokenScheme: true
      }), http);
    },
    deps: [Http]
  }),
  provide(User, {useClass: User}),
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' })
]);
```

This works fine. I then wrote a little `AuthService` that makes the calls to my backend and handles login/logout and the storage of the JWT. Here I want to use the `AuthHttp` Provider. As I read in the docs: When I inject a Service with provide at root level, Angular know how to get it when I use it at another point (meaning in another service). But I get an `cannot find name authHttp` error.

My `AuthService` looks like this:

```
import { Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  token: any;
  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();

  constructor(private router: Router, private authHttp: AuthHttp, private user: User) {}

  saveJwt(jwt: any) {
    if(jwt) {
      localStorage.setItem('auth_token', jwt);
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    }
  }

  deleteJwt() {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

  isAuth() {
    var decoded: any;
    decoded = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token);
    var date = new Date(0);
    date.setUTCSeconds(decoded.exp);
    if(date === null) {
      return false;
    }
    return (date.valueOf() > (new Date(0).valueOf()));
  }

  login(user: User) {
    var header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.authHttp.post('http://localhost:4000/sessions', JSON.stringify({ email: user.email, password: user.password }), {
      headers: header
    })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('Logged id');
        this.saveJwt(data.auth_token);
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => this.router.navigate(['Home'])
    );
  }

  logout() {
    this.deleteJwt();
    this.router.navigate(['Home']);
  }

}
```

I am then using `AuthService` in a `LoginComponent`. Like so:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { COMMON_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';
import { User } from '../shared/models/user.model';

@Component ({
  selector: 'login',
  moduleId: module.id,
  directives: [COMMON_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [AuthService],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    public user: User
  ) {}

  submitted = false;

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.auth.login(this.user);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.user));
  }

  // TODO: Remove when done
  get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.user); }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what the problem is. Do you get an error message? Where do you get the error? What are you trying to accomplish? Where do you inject `AuthService`?

Comment: I am injecting AuthHttp while Bootstrapping (as you see above). I want to use it in AuthService. The error I get is `Cannot find name 'AuthHttp'.`

Comment: But where and how do you use AuthService. You need to add it to providers (as shown in my answer).

Comment: I'm having the problem with using AuthHttp in AuthService. Not with AuthService itself. Oh man, it is always difficult to explain and track a problem with such a complex framework and so much code by just showing little bits of it.

Comment: I need to see code. How do you use `AuthService`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I added the code of the loginComponent. Thanks for helping

Comment: Ok, so you provide it at component level. That's fine of course. I built a simplified Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/DMdSS6?p=preview but have to leave for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `AuthService` to the providers as well

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(AuthHttp, {
    useFactory: (http: any) => {
      return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        headerPrefix: 'Bearer',
        tokenName: 'auth_token',
        globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type':'application/json'}],
        noJwtError: true,
        noTokenScheme: true
      }), http);
    },
    deps: [Http]
  }),
  provide(User, {useClass: User}),
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' }),
  AuthService
]);
```

Comment: Nope. Now I get Cannot find name 'AuthService' in my loginComponent